# Remove the exact row after sorting the table in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the code

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<p>Click the table headers to change the sorting order:</p>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
  <th>Sl no</th>
<th ng-click="orderByMe('name')">Name</th>
<th ng-click="orderByMe('country')">Country</th>
<th>Delete</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:myOrderBy">
  <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
<td>{{x.name}}</td>
<td>{{x.country}}</td>
<td><button type="button" ng-click="Delete($index)">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
        {name:'Carl',country:'Sweden'},
        {name:'Margareth',country:'England'},
        {name:'Hege',country:'Norway'},
        {name:'Joe',country:'Denmark'},
        {name:'Gustav',country:'Sweden'},
        {name:'Birgit',country:'Denmark'},
        {name:'Mary',country:'England'},
        {name:'Kai',country:'Norway'}
        ];
    $scope.orderByMe = function(x) {
        $scope.myOrderBy = x;
    }
    $scope.Delete = function(index){
      $scope.names.splice(index, 1);
    };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here at first if I want to delete a row it works fine, but if I sort once by name or country, then everytime the the unwanted row get deleted. Can any one help me in this. Here is the plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Az0c6IzCIuB87hac9wgN?p=preview). 
Thanks

Comment: Instead of index, send the actual object and remove it from `delete()`. Inside `delete`, use `$scope.names.splice($scope.names.indexOf(x), 1);`.
 [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/cjwhZBwpjs7nOziiPEtP?p=preview)

Comment: Or, have a reference to your `filtered` array and use that `$scope.names.splice($scope.names.indexOf($scope.filtered[index]), 1)`.. [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/gyjaEeyMe2rHCcVlKKuf?p=preview)

Comment: Accept @tanmay ans. It's good way.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways you would want to solve this:

1. As mentioned in comments by @Tushar, send whole object instead of just the `index` and in `delete` function, you could have:

   ```
   $scope.names.splice($scope.names.indexOf(x), 1);
   ```

   [Demo provided](http://plnkr.co/edit/cjwhZBwpjs7nOziiPEtP?p=preview) by him
2. Alternatively, you can have a reference of your filtered array like this:

   ```
   ng-repeat="x in filtered = (names | orderBy:myOrderBy)"
   ```

   And, inside `delete`, you can use that to find the object index in your original array:

   ```
   $scope.Delete = function(index){
     $scope.names.splice($scope.names.indexOf($scope.filtered[index]), 1);
   };
   ```

   [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/y0FPdMYw5kLBLpEJSiKQ?p=preview) for this approach

Comment: Thanks for attribution :)

Answer (score 1):

Use foreach. Try like below..

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<p>Click the table headers to change the sorting order:</p>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
  <th>Sl no</th>
<th ng-click="orderByMe('name')">Name</th>
<th ng-click="orderByMe('country')">Country</th>
<th>Delete</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in reArrange = (names | orderBy:myOrderBy)">
  <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
<td>{{x.name}}</td>
<td>{{x.country}}</td>
<td><button type="button" ng-click="Delete(x)">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
        {name:'Carl',country:'Sweden'},
        {name:'Margareth',country:'England'},
        {name:'Hege',country:'Norway'},
        {name:'Joe',country:'Denmark'},
        {name:'Gustav',country:'Sweden'},
        {name:'Birgit',country:'Denmark'},
        {name:'Mary',country:'England'},
        {name:'Kai',country:'Norway'}
        ];
    $scope.orderByMe = function(x) {
        $scope.myOrderBy = x;
    }
    $scope.Delete = function(x){
            //$scope.names.splice($scope.names.indexOf($scope.reArrange[index]), 1); // pass index
      angular.forEach($scope.names, function (value, index) {

          if (x.name == value.name) {
    $scope.names.splice(index,1)
          }
        })
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Explanation please!

Comment: we are comparing the values. Which is same then splice by index

Comment: What if `name` is duplicate in the data?

Comment: if id is same we can splice. or else compare directly like object == object

Comment: Yes, his will work on unique IDs. You cannot compare objects with `==`. You can check my comment on question to solve this problem.

Comment: We can compare but It's bad approach.. http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html

Comment: You both are experts man. I am just a beginner. Is it right way of approach that i have written the code in below answer

Comment: Dude everyone is beginner only. We are learning every day in different things.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is to pass the object on delete and remove it form the array using underscore.js
[Check this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PzmNeRtLlaTco9Gg8Iw7)

```
<td>
  <button type="button" ng-click="Delete(x)">Delete</button>
</td>
```

...

```
$scope.Delete = function(item){
      $scope.names = _.without($scope.names, _.findWhere($scope.names, item));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Now the delete function is working exactly as I want.

```
      $scope.Delete = function(name) {
    var index = -1;
    var comArr = eval($scope.names);
    for (var i = 0; i < comArr.length; i++) {
      if (comArr[i].name === name) {
        index = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (index === -1) {
      alert("Something gone wrong");
    }
    $scope.names.splice(index, 1);
  };
```

Here is the plunker link : http://plnkr.co/edit/Az0c6IzCIuB87hac9wgN?p=preview